# Drop down with pagination in gsp

Tags: java, gsp

I am trying to built a pop-up or drop down. Basically i needed to get bunch of data from the database and show it on the UI, so the User is able to select one of them as an option. The problem here is the count of data being fetched from database is more , i need to some how set some pagination in the drop down or popup.

Here is the code snippet below.

```
<g:if test="${vendor == CommonConstants.VENDOR_TELENOR}">
             <g:applyLayout name="form/select">
                <content tag="label"><g:message code="order.label.icc.number"/></content>
               <g:select name="deviceline-${index}.iccNumber"
                                  from="${iccNumbers}"
                                  optionKey="${{it} }"
                                  optionValue="${{it} }"
                                  />
            </g:applyLayout>
         </g:if>
```

Any Suggestion is Appreciated , Thanks